# Using Facebook from kiosks

Tags: security, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

Our company has developed photo kiosks allowing users to photograph themselves (with a custom frame highlighting the location) and post it on facebook (using the facebook.com/dialog/oauth for login/authorization).  Too many of our users get the additional security questions (probably because they are some distance from home).  Is there a way to get our company, application, or IP addresses registered as "trusted" so as to avoid the added security questions?